What philosophical works justify God’s simplicity?
I understand that simplicity is a concept that is often open to interpretation in philosophy. But this is philosophy, and you’d be hard pressed to find any matter that isn’t widely contested upon or disagreed upon.
Despite this, I cannot for the life of me comprehend how an entity who is all powerful (and thus can do anything) and all knowing (and thus knows every moment of everyone’s life and every speck of dust in the universe), can be anything but complex.
In the words of Dawkins (and I know many on this site have a distaste for him, but it is hard for me to disagree here),

How can you possibly say God is a “simple”, “unitary” explanation for the universe and the laws of physics, given that, in order to create it, he needed to know a whole lot of physics and mathematics. Plus, 4.6 billion years later, he now has the bandwidth to read the intimate thoughts of seven billion of people simultaneously, and, for all we know, the thoughts and prayers of even more billions of extra-terrestrial aliens.


It didn’t surprise me that Swinburne still thinks God is a supremely simple entity. He evidently uses the word “simple” in a special theological sense. What does surprise me is the number of others incapable of seeing the absurdity of his position. Several Twitter responses to the debate proudly proclaim “Divine Simplicity” as a thing in theology. But you can’t demonstrate that something is right merely by shoving the word “Divine” in front of it, not even if you attribute it to Augustine or Thomas Aquinas. What is the justification for invoking “Divine Simplicity in this context? Does it even mean anything coherent?

There is, of course, the doctrine of divine simplicity (SEP) but the doctrine mainly focuses upon God’s transcendent nature of having no parts, and the “simplicity”, even per the doctrine, has more to do with how God is constituted, rather than what He does or can do, from a functional standpoint.
There are already many responses to this doctrine anyhow, but what I am more interested in is theist philosophers who argued that God is simple in every which way, such as in both structure and function. Or to make the request more easily tractable, I am interested in any philosophers who have argued that God is a relatively simpler entity than something like the initial conditions of the universe.

EDIT:
Here is a long-ish quote from Dawkins explaining what he means by simplicity:

Here’s what I mean by simple. I suspect it captures what most biologists mean, if not most scientists. It can be quantified using an intuitive, verbal version of Shannon’s mathematical measure of information. Simple is the opposite of complex. The complexity or simplicity of an entity is the minimum number of words (more strictly bits – binary digits in the most economical re-coding) you need to describe it. A centipede and a lobster both consist of a train of segments running from front to rear. The centipede is simpler than the lobster, in the following sense. To describe the centipede, you admittedly need a special description of the front and rear segments, but the many segments in between are the same as each other. Just describe one segment, and then say “Repeat repeat repeat . . . some large number of times” (it might literally be 100 times in some species.) But you can’t do that with the lobster because most of the segments are different from each other. If you were to write a book called The Anatomy of the Centipede and another book called the Anatomy of the Lobster, the second book would come out a lot fatter. Assuming, of course, that the two books go into a similar level of detail, which is an easy assumption to police.


From this you can see that simplicity/complexity is measured not just by number of parts but also by what Julian Huxley called “heterogeneity of parts”. And we have to add that the heterogeneous parts themselves, and the way they are connected up, are necessary to the definition of the entity concerned. Any old heap of junk has a large number of heterogenous parts but neither they, nor their particular juxtaposition, are necessary to the general definition of “a heap of junk”. You can shuffle the parts of a  heap of junk a million times, and all million will answer to the definition of a heap of junk. The heterogenous parts of a lobster, and their mutual arrangement, are necessary to the definition of a lobster. So they are to the definition of a centipede, but fewer of them are different from each other, and you can shuffle (most of them) into any order.


Divine simplicity is contested even within Christian Theology -- see Alvin Plantinga's critiques.

Any philosophical work that which alludes to an intuitive grasp intended onto Scotus-like univocal haecceity not the usual universality would do...

If there was a god, and the god was super-complex... how would we, or anyone, know?
If there was a god, and the god was super-simple... how would we, or anyone, know?
And how can anyone think they could know, or claim they could know?
And why would anyone think someone else could know, or have a more valid guess?

@shindemo not sure what you’re trying to say, sounds almost as unclear as divine simplicity itself

@AlistairRiddoch we don’t have to know, but we can make reasonable judgments about the entity’s complexity to then decide if he exists in the first place. A more complex being seems a priori less likely to exist

There is one reasonable argument that can be made. God is usually supposed to be complex because it is said to be an intelligent entity, and intelligence is complex.
But does intelligence actually have to be complex? Marcus Hutter, an artificial intelligence researcher, developed a framework called AIXI which, under reasonable assumptions, has been proved to be an optimal reinforcement learning agent. Reinforcement learning (RL) agents observe their environment over time, receive rewards over time, form a model of what's going on, and select an action at each time step in an attempt to maximize the long-term reward that will be received. Better RL agents get larger long-term rewards, on average. RL agents such as AIXI could in theory succeed at any task - playing chess, writing sonnets, building a house - and therefore, arguably, a good enough RL agent would be intelligent in a sense.
The behavior of AIXI - the action it takes at each time step - can be summarized by a reasonably short formula:

Now, this formula is reasonably short, although to fully define AIXI there is some more explanation needed of what all the terms mean. To briefly summarize, AIXI performs ideal Bayesian inference to select a hypothesis of how the world works, and then takes an action to maximize its expected reward, under the assumption the world works that way. (Let me mention that although AIXI is theoretically optimal, the reason it is not used for practical AI is that it takes far, far too much time to calculate - much worse than exponential time.)
What matters (from the perspective of Occam's razor) is that the formula for AIXI is short in comparison to formulas giving the laws of physics, which may be the case; at least, it's not obviously longer than the formulas we have the laws of physics.
The formula does describe an agent that is intelligent in some way. The agent it describes is not God, of course, but it is in a sense intelligent, and therefore it is conceivable that an intelligent being might be fairly simple, and that therefore a "God" entity might be described by a different, fairly simple formula.
There is, however, one big problem.
The (known) laws of physics are not only simple, but also we know that they (mostly) match observations. We can use them quantitatively to predict and explain. That wouldn't be true for a God-formula, because the actions of a superintelligent being would be almost impossible to predict.
Let T be the hypothesis, "the universe operates according to a simple, unintelligent Theory of Everything formula, F1, similar in kind to what physicists have discovered so far," and G be the hypothesis, "the universe operates according to a simple formulaic intelligence formula, F2, similar in kind to AIXI," and let O be our observations of the universe. We want to compare P(G|O) to P(T|O); is one a lot larger than the other?
For the physics-like theory, Bayes' formula says P(T|O) = P(O|T) P(T)/P(O). P(T), the prior probability of the theory, is fairly high; that's what simplicity gains us. P(O|T) is also fairly high; the theory specifically predicts the observations we see - to pick one example, it specifically tells us how a moving electron will curve in the presence of a magnet, in a way that matches our observations very exactly. And therefore P(T|O) will be high.
Bayes' formula says P(G|O) = P(O|G) P(G)/P(O). P(G), the prior probability of G, is reasonably high; that's, again, what simplicity gains us. But there's also that P(O|G) term. A priori we have no idea how the superintelligent entity described by the formula F2 would specifically act; what if it would prefer a universe with a 10% faster speed of light? Then G would predict all the wrong observations! There are infinite choices an intelligent creator might make (in accordance with the specific formula F2 which dictates its behavior), all of which but one would deviate from our actual observations. Therefore, P(O|G) would be very low. Which means P(G|O) is also low.
So to summarize, we have P(T|O) = P(O|T) P(T)/P(O) = (big number) * (big number) / P(O), and P(G|O) = P(O|G) P(G)/P(O) = (tiny tiny number) * (big number) / P(O). So P(T|O) wins, by a lot.

Good answer. It seems that one can increase the P (O|G) term if one gerrymanders the observations into the hypothesis. However, this would correspondingly lower the P(G) term.

God as a reinforcement learning agent...and I love the formula, very beautiful. So when God sat down to establish the DNA sequence of a leopard he was working out the hypotheses of what would happen if He would place a guanine nucleotide next to a adenine nucleotide (or maybe better still, a cytosine nucleotide). It would be like Dawkins centipede, but a mindbogglingly long one. The hypotheses also had to deal with the behaviour of the gazelle DNA which in turn had to deal with the grass DNA... But +1, I love the idea!

One very crucial issue (apart from the one mentioned) is that this formulation of "intelligence" is inextricably linked to learning. It's a formula for learning, more than it's a formula for intelligence. The intelligence reduces to incremental learning steps through repeated applications of this formula (combined with some external data), which would be fundamentally different from something simply being intelligent from the "start" (which is the only proposal for a simple god I've ever seen... although they're proposed to be "timeless", whatever that means)

Maybe there is a misunderstanding...
The objections to the "divine simplicity" based on the complexity of the universe and considering "what He does or can do, from a functional standpoint" do not consider the theologians point of view about God.
They reflect the scientists point of view that analyze a mechanism or organism and thus asks for "parts and functions".
In addition to classical sources: Anselm, Aquinas it may help to consider the metaphysics of Spinoza, an atheist; see Ethics (1677), Part I: Concerning God.
Obviously, this is a sketch and not an analysis, but IMO it helps to understand the relevant aspects of the metaphysical approach:

Def III. By substance, I mean that which is in itself, and is conceived through itself: in other words, that of which a conception can be formed independently of any other conception.


Def VI. By God, I mean a being absolutely infinite—that is, a substance consisting in infinite attributes, of which each expresses eternal and infinite essentiality.


Def VIII. By eternity, I mean existence itself, in so far as it is conceived necessarily to follow solely from the definition of that which is eternal.

The the author list a series of propositions, deduced from previous Definitions and some, seemingly obvious, Axioms:

Prop. VII. Existence belongs to the nature of substances.


Prop. VIII. Every substance is necessarily infinite.


Prop. XI. God, or substance, consisting of infinite attributes, of which each expresses eternal and infinite essentiality, necessarily exists.


Prop. XIII. Substance absolutely infinite is indivisible.


Prop. XIV. Besides God no substance can be granted or conceived.

What does it mean? That God, being substance, i.e. the "primary" metaphyscal entuty, is eternal and infinite but "undivided", i.e. it has no parts that can be separated from it: not only physically, but conceptually as well.
Thus, the universe: mind and matter, are not separated from God. They are neither "parts" of God; they are modifications, i.e. waves on the surface of substance.

So in short, a theologian's answer will never satisfy a scientist and vice versa. No way, no how, not ever. Woe betide you if you find yourself somewhere in the middle... Just pick a side and move on, you're messing up the game.

"The objections ... do not consider the theologians point of view about God" - this is a questionable (/ false) statement. We do consider theologians point of view. We see them presenting an unjustified assertion based on a fuzzy or incoherent definition. We evaluate that assertion via the closest coherent definition, and we get to the exact opposite conclusion. If we stuck to their definition, the discourse would be little more than a back and forth of: "nuh uh" "yuh uh", because you can't do much more than that with something fuzzy or incoherent.

First of all, Jacques Derrida understandably referred to the "God" word as a "transcendental signifier" meaning what it refers to has, for a long time, meant many different things to different people, so the following is just one version:
Bishop Robert Barron says much the same about 'the many versions' at the start of his video: Who God Is & Who God Isn't, and then (within 2 1/2 minutes) has interpreted Saint Thomas Aquinas by saying God is the 'existence' that makes the world exist.
So taking it from there, God is existence, existence grounds the world (as existing): i.e. the explanation for the existence of the world is existence i.e. God.
So, as I look at a nearby pepper pot, what is existence? First of all it isn't just the pepper pot on its own. It involves me looking at the pepper pot thinking about it. So existence involves everything that makes it possible for me to be looking at the pepper pot contemplating its existence, including the origin of the pepper pot. We'll come back to this.
As the ground of existing things, existence cannot be a 'thing'. [Existence could not explain why things exist if existence was one of those things to be explained.] Also existence cannot be defined since by the process of definition: definitio fit per genus proximum et differentiam specificam Wikipedia, "a definition must be made by specifying the next higher genus and the specific difference". But existence is already the highest genus.
So existence is indeterminate (not an thing), and indefinable, and whatever it is—not that it can exists in the usual sense—is at least everything that facilitates me being able to contemplate a pepper pot.
Whatever existence is, (not that it 'is'), is very simple in its elusive indeterminacy, and yet is it what makes all existing things exist.  I hope that reveals some possible simplicity, which can at the same time be the awesome ground of everything.
When Heidegger philosophically analyses Being [ref. to philosophical works] he makes such observations on existence, but he doesn't call it God. (He tried this some years earlier and found prior bagsies on the "God" word.) But we can just hook it round to Bishop Barron's interpretation of Saint Thomas and leave it at that.
